# LoadRunner VuGen Script Replay Failing for Citrix Module Login

Tags: testing, automation, loadrunner, citrix, vugen

I am using LoadRunner VuGen to record a test I would like to execute using a Citrix module. I am able to successfully record the actions but when I play the actions back, it stops at the following line of code:

```
ctrx_wait_for_event("LOGON", CTRX_LAST);
```

The Citrix ICA Client screen is displayed and it is waiting for the Username, Password, and Domain to be entered by I am unable to manually enter the information in and after a couple a seconds it fails. When I initially record my actions, I am logging into Citrix via a web URL. But when I play back the actions it goes directly to the Citrix ICA Client screen without ever opening the URL.

Comment: When you say it's waiting for Username, Password, and Domain do you mean you're seeing a Windows-like login screen?

Answer (score 0):

This is Citrix application where Logging into the Citrix Desktop is taking too much time than the parameterized hence throwing the TimeOut Error.

In the error if the IP address is also mentioned, then it is usually is a citrix connectivity/network connectivity issue.

We had a similar error without any IP address, we did the following which resolved the issue:

Check if there are any active citrix sessions, if yes clear/terminate all the sessions. Then run the VuGen script from VuGen and dont try manually
Upgrade the ICA client if it is older than 13, we are using 14.x version